# Relation between elements of essential spectrum and the eigenvalue of a self adjoint operator

Tags: functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory, spectral-theory, perturbation-theory

Relation between elements of essential spectrum and the eigenvalue of a self adjoint operator. In particular, is there any way we can say that the element of essential spectrum is an eigenvalue of infinite multiplicities of a self adjoint operator.

Any idea or if there any article related to this concepts or any book will be helpful.